# Select N items directly before a given ID

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a row for each of the alphanumerically ordered items (ids) below:

```
aa ab ac ba cc cf ff gh h4 ia
```

I would like to select the **3 items directly prior** to `cc`, which would be `ab`, `ac` and `ba` (in that order). My MySQL query does not pick the items directly prior to `cc`, but rather from the beginning of the list.

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE id < 'cc' ORDER BY id LIMIT 3.
```

Again, this query does not work because it does not retrieve the items **directly** before `cc`. What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close:

```
SELECT *
FROM things
WHERE id < 'cc'
ORDER BY id DESC
------------^
LIMIT 3;
```

You need to sort the items in descending order to get the "biggest" ones before `'cc'`.

Also, for three items you want `limit 3`.  I assume the "2" is a typo.

If you then want these in alphabetical order, use a subquery and order again:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM things t
      WHERE id < 'cc'
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 3
     ) t
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: I did come up with the same approach but didn't manage to figure out that I needed to also add a subquery to re-sort the list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change order, limit and reverse order again:

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT * FROM things
     WHERE id < 'cc'
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT 3
 ) t
ORDER BY id ASC
```